# Finding Elements in Linq to XML

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

So I have this XML file that I generate, it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Members xmlns="urn:lst-emp:emp">
  <Member xmlns="">
    <!--Info for Member TESTER-->
    <AccountName>Test Name</AccountName>
    <AccountNumber>Test Number</AccountNumber>
    <AccountBalance>Test Balance</AccountBalance>
  </Member>
  <Member xmlns="">
    <!--Info for Member Jeff Reed-->
    <AccountName>Jeff Reed</AccountName>
    <AccountNumber>5929</AccountNumber>
    <AccountBalance>9223.01</AccountBalance>
  </Member>
</Members>
```

I can search through the entire XML for AccountName using the method below, but after it comes up as a match, I need a way to get that cooresponding xElements AccountNumber to validate it's PIN (Account Number) is equal to the one in my password textbox.

```
internal static bool userExists(String validationName)
    {
        bool foundUser = false;
        //check for a name
        XElement xelement = XElement.Load(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath + "\\members.xml");
        IEnumerable<XElement> members = xelement.Elements();
        foreach (var member in members)
        {
            if (member.Element("AccountName").Value == validationName)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("It's a match.");
                foundUser = true;
                return foundUser;
            }
            else
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("No match found.");
            }
        }
        return foundUser;
    }
```

How do I go about doing this? I've considered turning it back into my BankMember object, but I need a way to parse the info from the matched username first.

```
        BankMember newMember = new BankMember(txtBxAccountName.Text.ToString(), int.Parse(txtBxAccountNumber.Text), float.Parse(txtBxStartingBalance.Text.TrimStart('$')));
```

Comment: You already know how to get `AccountName`, you can get `AccountNumber` in exactly the same way: `member.Element("AccountNumber").Value`.

Comment: Also, never ever use `float` or `double` to represent monetary values.

Comment: But how do I find that specific elements AccountNumber? I search through every AccountName for a match, but once I find the element it matches, I need to find it's AccountNumber.

Comment: Ehm, once you find the element it matches, *you have the element it matches*, which is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code give you the account number of the matching element,

```
members.Where(x=> x.Element("AccountName").Value==validationName).Select(x=> x.Element("AccountNumber").Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I think `Single()` would make more sense than `FirstOrDefault()` here.

Comment: @svick: Yes. but better to use `SingleOrDefault()`

Comment: How do I go about overwriting that value I found?

Answer (score 0):

Parent is the key. Something like this:

```
    internal static XElement FindMember(String validationName)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath + "\\members.xml");

        XElement accountNameElement = doc.Root
                                         .Elements("Member")
                                         .Elements("AccountName")
                                         .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Value == validationName);

        if (accountNameElement != default(XElement))
            return accountNameElement.Parent;
        return default(XElement);
    }
```

invoked like this:

```
        XElement memberElement= FindMember("Test Name");
        if (memberElement== default(XElement))
            Console.WriteLine("Not Found");
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found {0}, {1}, {2}"
                , memberElement.Element("AccountName").Value
                , memberElement.Element("AccountNumber").Value
                , memberElement.Element("AccountBalance").Value);
        }
```